# How to force img to resize with parent Grid container Materual UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to force the image inside a Grid to resize wto the size of the parent Grid. tried minheight and height but doesn't seem to be working. Also tried a styled component.

```
    return (
    <Grid container sx={{ margin: '50px 0 40px 0'}} justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
        <Grid item container sm={10} md={6} direction='column' justifyContent='flex-start'>
            <Typography sx={{ margin: '20px 20px 20px 0'}} variant='h2'>
                NFT Louvre
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ margin: '20px 20px 20px 0'}} variant='h4'>
                See Human Art through an AI's eyes
            </Typography>
            <Typography sx={{ margin: '20px 20px 20px 0'}} variant='h6'>
                Featured Collection: Bouquets - Genesis
            </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={10} md={6}>
            <img sx={{minHeight: '100%', minWidth: '100%'}} src={gif} alt='Bouquets - Genesis'/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
        <Grid item sm={10} md={6}>
          <Box position="relative" width="100%" height="100%">
            <span style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, backgroundSize: 'cover', backgroundPosition: 'center', backgroundImage: `url(${gif})` }} />
          </Box>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Similar to this.
https://mui.com/components/buttons/#complex-button

Comment: I ended up using Card and CardMedia and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your answer!